# making a variable that is true for elements corresponding with elements of another variable

Tags: python, pandas, variables, element

I have currently created a variable from a csv file called regions including multiple regions. the file has data for the regions ethnicity percentages.

regions is currently showing all regions .

how do I make a new variable called London that is a series with true in the elements corresponding to London elements in regions and false otherwise?

then how would I make a new data frame for London_by_eth that contains the rows from regions_by_eth that correspond to London

thank you

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? `london = regions['city'] == 'London'`

Comment: This kind of thing should be explained in any pandas tutorial, it's one of the most basic dataframe operations.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you better or with more detail, it would be helpful to have more context.

I'm going to assume you have read the csv file as panda dataframe and that your regions DataFrame contains a column called 'Region' that contains values called 'London'.

Then you can create a boolean list to check if `regions` is `London`:

```
is_london = regions['Region'] == 'London'
```

Then using that you can create a new dataframe containing rows corresponding to London:

```
London_by_eth = regions[is_london].copy()
```